# Could not Free Realloc Allocated Memory in C

Tags: c, heap-memory, realloc, heap-corruption

My code is working fine until I try to free the allocated memory. I `malloc`ed the `files` pointer, and later on I used `realloc` to increase the size. But then it gives me invalid pointer error when I try to free the memory, not sure why.

```
char *files = malloc(1);
char *temp = strdup(argv[i]);
strcat(temp, "/");
strcat(temp, dp->d_name);
DIR *child_dir;
child_dir = opendir (temp);

if (child_dir == NULL) {
    files = realloc(files, strlen(dp->d_name)+1);
    strcat(files, dp->d_name);
    strcat(files, "/");
} else {
    struct dirent *child_dp;
    while ((child_dp = readdir (child_dir)) != NULL) {
        if (!strcmp(child_dp->d_name, ".")
            || !strcmp(child_dp->d_name, ".."))
                continue;

        files = realloc(files, strlen(child_dp->d_name) + 1);
        strcat(files, child_dp->d_name);
        strcat(files, "/");
    }
}
close(fd[0]);
int n = write(fd[1], files, strlen(files));
free(temp); // free
free(files); // free
temp = NULL;
files = NULL;
return;
```

This is the error I am getting,

```
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x721af)[0x7fa2e697c1af]
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x77706)[0x7fa2e6981706]
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x78453)[0x7fa2e6982453]
./myfind[0x40110c]
./myfind[0x400b02]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5)[0x7fa2e692a6e5]
./myfind[0x400a09]
======= Memory map: ========
```

Note: If I run the same code without freeing any memory space, it works fine. Which means that the pointers are pointing to the correct location in the memory.

Comment: You're causing undefined behavior when you do `strcat(temp, "/");`. `temp` is only big enough for the `argv[i]` string that you copied it from, it doesn't have room for you to concatenate additional strings to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're corrupting your heap with this code:

```
char *temp = strdup(argv[i]);
strcat(temp, "/");
strcat(temp, dp->d_name);
```

`strdup` only allocates enough space for the string it's duplicating, but you then concatenate more onto the end without reallocating to make room.

You're also not leaving space for the `NUL` terminator when you `realloc` `files` in the `if` condition, though in most cases you'll get away with that (you should allocate the correct amount though).

Lastly, in the `while` loop of the `else` case, each `realloc` is only allocating enough for the stuff you're adding, but not leaving space for what already exists (and again, no space is left for the `NUL` terminator). The repeated misuse is guaranteed heap corruption after a while.

Comment: *"in most cases you'll get away with that"*, I'm not sure that may not leave the wrong impression.... maybe the parenthetical should read (*"if you fail to allocate the correct about of memory -- you should be shot!"*), or maybe just *"-- Undefined Behavior results"* `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: Yeah, I'm just pointing out that there are mistakes that often don't cause symptoms on some or all compilers/systems, so "it works" isn't enough to say the code is correct.

Comment: Yes, I understood the crux of what you were saying, it just struck me as a bit odd/humorous on this Friday evening (thus the `:)`